# How can I undo `setsid gnome-shell --replace`?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, xubuntu, gnome-shell

I entered this command misunderstanding what would happen and it changed all my desktop manager settings. I already rebooted twice (and selected Xubuntu as usual) but some settings are still changed. I have fewer workspaces than before, there's an annoying sound whenever I press backspace too often, I have a panel at the top of my main monitor that has no setting to remove it, and my keyboard shortcuts don't work anymore.

I checked out [How can I undo `gnome-shell --replace`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673295/how-can-i-undo-gnome-shell-replace) and it didn't help, please don't mark this as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was an old saved session that it kept reloading to. I deleted it via the Session and Startup application and have my non-shitty settings back.