# IntelliJ and Scenebuilder

Tags: intellij

I recently installed IntelliJ and SceneBuilder on Ubuntu, and when I want to open a .fxml in IntelliJ it asks me to locate the executable. But I can't seem to find anything executable which has something to do with SceneBuilder. I just downloaded and installed the .deb-file of SceneBuilder. What to do?

Comment: You can try rebooting to see if file associations get updated.

Comment: @Zacharee1 And why should a reboot solve the problem?

Comment: Please add the file name of the deb file into your question. And give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: @Zacharee1 and you should read this ;) http://askubuntu.com/q/672223/367165

Comment: The .deb-file I installed was named scenebuilder-8.0.0.deb, @A.B.

Answer (score 2):

The executable is

```
/opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder
```

Why? That's why.

1. `dpkg -L scenebuilder | grep bin`

   gives no output, ok, let's continute with step 2
2. `dpkg -L scenebuilder | grep desktop`

   gives

   ```
   /opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder.desktop
   ```

   and

   ```
   grep 'Exec=' /opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder.desktop
   ```

   gives

   ```
   Exec=/opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder
   ```

   and that's your executable.

---

You could also use

```
find /opt/SceneBuilder -type f -executable
```

but in the installation are so many attributes set incorrectly, that makes no sense. The output of the command has 99 entries.

Comment: I wasn't able to find it yesterday, put I'll check later an give you an update. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: **@Recusiwe** Don't thank **A.B.**!  **;-)** If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!