# I keep getting a "python2.7-minimal" error. Any help?

Tags: java, downloads

I am getting this error when I try to install anything. I try

`sudo apt-get install python2.7-minimal`. It won't work. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code again.

```
E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'python2.7-minimal'.Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
```

Comment: please let me know your progress =)

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and execute:

```
  sudo apt-get install -o APT::Immediate-Configure=false -f apt python-minimal
```

If you experience a dependency issue, such like

```
libglib2.0-0: Recommends: libglib2.0-data but it is not going to be installed
```

execute these commands:

```
  sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo apt-get install -o APT::Immediate-Configure=false -f apt python-minimal
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  sudo apt-get autoremove
```

<sub>source [here](http://tkurek.blogspot.in/2013/04/could-not-perform-immediate.html)</sub>

For reference [here](http://tkurek.blogspot.in/2013/04/issues-with-python-minimal-during.html)

Comment: Please explain why it's necessary to reboot

Comment: @A.B failed to justify the presence of the command wrt [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/672223/when-is-it-necessary-to-reboot-an-ubuntu-system) ,So deleted :)