# Do applications need to be stopped before upgrading packages or restarted after upgrading packages?

Tags: upgrade, package-management, updates

Are there situations where applications/processes need to be closed before running apt-get dist upgrade?

If so, out of curiosity what happens if you run apt-get dist upgrade anyways, without stopping the application first?

If not, do you need to restart the application after the upgrade?

I'm asking because I have a server running Ubuntu, and I am thinking about having a cron job automatically run apt-get dist upgrade every so often.

Also, it is my understanding that a reboot shouldn't be necessary unless there is a kernel update.

Answer (score 0):

No process in a server environment need to be stopped/closed during an update with the package manager. The installation and removal scripts in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` start and stop the services for you, if it's necessary. Mostly it's only a `reload`, e.g.

```
sudo systemctl reload service_name
```

or a `restart`

```
sudo systemctl restart service_name
```

A reboot is usually also not necessary. Read this [When is it necessary to reboot an Ubuntu system?](https://askubuntu.com/q/672223/367165).